# Where do I ask ISP (Internet service/network service providers) related technical questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I want to know details about IMEI numbers are used, be it for networking or blacklisting etc - the tech stack behind it.

I went over to [Network Engineering](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com) but I'm not sure if that's the right place.

Comment: That's a very broad question. What specifically about ISPs do you need to know? Because general support queries for ISP support would be better off on the specific ISP support forums, not Stack Exchange.

Comment: Is it about suggestions? which one is better? or is it about settings for a specific ISP? or something else?

Answer (score 5):

If the question is about settings, then the best place would be the ISP directly, try the customer service for example.

If it's about ISP in a different country if you are travelling there temporary, then [Travel.SE](http://travel.stackexchange.com) is the place, we have plenty of these questions there.

If it's about *network related* stuff such as port forwarding, triggers, etc., then [Super User](http://superuser.com) is the place, *not* Network Engineering for sure.

Comment: Heidel, what makes Super User more appropriate than Network Engineering for "network related stuff such as port forwarding, triggers, etc"?

Comment: @alexander Read the tour page of each site and you will know.